# Is it possible to make an image accessable from development mode AND production mode in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have been developing my App with Angular in development mode, now i wanted to build it into production mode to host it on my Synology Web Server.

In Development mode I saved a picture in /assets/pictures/pic_1.png, this runs fine, but when I go into prod mode I am getting this Error Message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4WJ1.jpg

This is how I implemented the picture:

```
<img src="../../assets/pictures/pic_1.png" />
```

With this Code it SHOULD show the picture BOTH in development and production mode.

Edit #1

Current Workaround:

I hosted the pictures in another folder of my Server which is accessable from the internet and I am getting the pictures with this code:

```
<img src="http://(x.x.x/apipfadipics/pic_1.png" />
```

Comment: What's your backend running on?

Comment: should be a apache server 2.4

Comment: `<img src="assets/pictures/pic_1.png" />` would work in both

Comment: yeah thank you !!!!!